# TypedFile Retrofit and rename file

Tags: android, retrofit

Using `Retrofit 1.9.`

`TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("image/jpg", new File(filePath));`

I want to rename the file uploaded to the server. how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like you can, since TypedFile is a thin wrapper around File.
When you post the upload, the file name in the multi-part upload comes from TypedFile.fileName(), which calls file.getName().

I can think of two options:

1. Copy / rename the file before constructing the TypedFile
2. Sub-class TypedFile, add an 'uploadFileName' member and 'setUploadFileName' methods, and then override the fileName() method to return this value instead of file.getName(), if the value is not null/empty.

I'd probably go with #2